# Solve the equations.

Tags: polynomials

> Solve for real numbers $x$ & $y$ :
>        $$xy^2=15x^2+17xy+15y^2$$
>        $$x^2y=20x^2+3y^2$$.

It is my problem. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x=0 \implies y=0\,$, otherwise let $y = tx$ and eliminate $x$ between:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x^\bcancel{3} t^2 &= 15\cancel{x^2}+17\cancel{x^2} t+15\cancel{x^2} t^2 \\
x^\bcancel{3} t &= 20\cancel{x^2} + 3\cancel{x^2}t^2
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$